# Проблема с обновлением в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET imgname ='".$imgname."' WHERE user='".$_SESSION['user']."'";
```

Так хочу обновить столбик `imgname` в таблице `users`, в сессии у меня имя `user`-а, но что-то не то. Не понимаю что. Помогите найти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

сделайте так:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) echo mysql_error();
```

Comment: спасибо больщое :)))

Comment: да не за что, просто примите ответ, если помог )))

Comment: получил то, что надо, и только его и видели В
пора бы ввести что-то, что заставляет принимать ответы..

Comment: Пора смотреть на % принятых ответов и не отвечать тем, у кого принятых ответов мало. =)

Comment: согласен с @ling

Comment: ну я смотрю - если хоть что то принято, значит человек уже знает где находится кнопка "принять ответ", а то бывает всяко - на половину моих вопросов, например, ответов нет.

Comment: просто у меня мало очков:(